# spring data jpa: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When I try to get the users using repository interface I received following exception ***"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!"***

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRelationshipRepository
        extends JpaRepository<UserRelationship, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<UserRelationship> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT ur.id.toUser FROM UserRelationship ur WHERE ur.fromUser = :fromUser AND ur.relationshipTypeId = 1")
    Set<User> findUserFriends(@Param("fromUser") User fromUser);
}
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.User", attributeNodes = {})
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8884184875433252086L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_id_seq", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "users_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fromUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserRelationship> relationships = new HashSet<UserRelationship>();
// getters setters
}

@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.UserRelationship", attributeNodes = {})
@Table(name = "users_relationships")
public class UserRelationship extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6367981399229734837L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private final UserRelationshipId id = new UserRelationshipId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "from_user_id", nullable = false)
    @MapsId("fromUserId") // maps fromUserId attribute of the embedded id
    private User fromUser;

    @Column(name = "relationship_type_id")
    private Long relationshipTypeId;

}
```

I am using '**1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT**' version of spring data jpa.
This is already known [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-885), and it is marked as resolved, but I am still get it.

Please, help me to solve this.

**Update:**
If I change repository method's return type to `Set<Object>` then all  works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into [DATAJPA-885](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-885), which is already fixed and will be part of the Spring Data Hopper SR2 release.

Comment: Thanks, for response. Could, you tell me the approximate date of release?

Comment: Please, let me know is it possible to get the solution?

Comment: We're shooting for June 15th. Feel free to give the snapshots a try! :)

Comment: Thanks for the info.