# Spring Data JPA giving error when joining over multiple tables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I have the following query which joins over multiple tables for getting the necessary output:

```
public interface UserRepositoryJpaRepository <User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT  o.id, u.id, u.name, i.name,i.id FROM User u, Item i LEFT JOIN u.order o  LEFT JOIN o.payment p WHERE p.id=:id AND o.id=i.order")
        List<MixedResult>getUsersWithOrderByPayment_id(@Param("id") Long id);
```

However, when running **Spring Boot 1.4.1** with **Spring Data JPA 1.10.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT**, I am getting the following error message :

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No aliases
>   found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in
>   result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!

However, I see that the generated SQL is fine  and it works

Comment: Why are you using snapshot version of Spring Data JPA? Can you repeat the same behaviour on a stable release?

Comment: Yes, I could repeat the same behavior with the 1.10.4.RELEASE version.I used the latest version because this error message seems to be bug in the stable version which is resolved only in the snapshot version [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658619/spring-data-jpa-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-make-sure-your-query-defines). Is it possible to create a object only for mapping the result of a JPQL query ?