# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Could someone please help with how to fix this  error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!`

The JPA query that causes this error is:

```
@Query("SELECT sm.messageCode, sm.messageDescription FROM SystemMessage sm WHERE UPPER(sm.messageTypeCode) = TRIM(UPPER(:messageTypeCodeEntered))")
    public List<Map<String, String>> returnCodeToDescMapping(@Param("messageTypeCodeEntered") String messageTypeCodeEntered);
```

I researched this error online but many of the questions seem to refer to not naming the Object, but I don't think I have that problem since I am using `sm`.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of spring-data are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring data jpa: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658619/spring-data-jpa-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-make-sure-your-query-defines)

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Data JPA can only return a `SystemMessage`, but you can make your @Query as:

```
@Query("SELECT sm FROM SystemMessage sm WHERE UPPER(sm.messageTypeCode) = TRIM(UPPER(:messageTypeCodeEntered))")
public List<SystemMessage> returnCodeToDescMapping(@Param("messageTypeCodeEntered") String messageTypeCodeEntered);
```

or as

```
//Message is a new class with constructor public Message(messageCode, messageDescription ){..}
@Query("select new Message(sm.messageCode as messageCode , sm.messageDescription as messageDescription) from SystemMessage sm where UPPER(sm.messageTypeCode) = TRIM(UPPER(:messageTypeCodeEntered))")
public List<Message> returnCodeToDescMapping(@Param("messageTypeCodeEntered") String messageTypeCodeEntered);
```