# Take2: spring data jpa: No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I get the same error as [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658619/spring-data-jpa-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-make-sure-your-query-defines)  However, I understand that issue (3 separate ones in fact) have been fixed.  I am using SD-JPA 1.11.1.RELEASE and SD-commons 1.31.1.RELEASE.

My use-case is completely different though.  I read that Spring Data JPA from 1.10.x+ supports sending back Java8 streams.   I also read that release 1.11.x+ supports using Projections.  Thus, I am trying to get a Projection returned in the Stream.  Stepping way into the debugger, I found that the `MyEntity` class below (**not** the `MyEntityProjection` class) is coming back in the Stream.

So my question: does anyone know if what I am trying is actually supported?  The documentation is not crystal clear on this point.

Here is an abstract of my code:

```
public interface MyEntityJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT me FROM MyEntity me WHERE me.id IN (:ids) ")
    Stream<MyEntityProjection> findAllAndStream(@Param("ids") Iterable<Long> ids);
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace  and the relevant code of the projection and the entity.

Comment: I would have; however, that is not really possible (working at a security company!)  Are you saying that this should work?  If so, why does the call to findallAndStream return 'MyEntity' objects and not the projections?

Comment: I'm just saying that it is impossible to help if we don't see what you are doing. Create an example that reproduces your problem. We don't have to see your production code.

Comment: I believe that we are kind of talking past one another here.  My question was whether or not Java8 Streams could return Projections - i.e. is that supported or not?  If not, then I don't need to create an example that doesn't work.  Since it IS non-trivial to create such an example, I did not want to spend a lot of time debugging my current code or to spend the time to create an example suitable for public consumption prior to knowing.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, projections in streams are supported. If they don't work it's either a Bug or something is wrong with your code.

Generally, all combinations of wrapper types (`Stream`s, `Collection`s, `Optional`, `Future`s and so on) should be freely combinable with actual result types (entities, projections, scalar types).